# Notepad++ - customised syntax highlighting

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to customise Notepad++ to perform **begin** and **end** matching when displaying the programming language Verilog?

I would like it to highlight the corresponding **begin** / **end** when my text cursor is over either of the two - identical to what happens when my text cursor is over an open or closed bracket, like this image explains:

[image: here]

Is there a general solution for altering syntax highlighting, specifically highlighting pairs of words/punctuation marks not specific to Verilog?

Comment: Would you mind providing a little more information? Specifically, is Verilog a programming language? Are you literally matching nested pairs of the words "begin" and "end"? Have you looked at any existing customizations, such as the plug-ins here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

Comment: @Dane I've added more information to the question now. Thanks for the link, I think what I'm looking for is a "lexer", I think I can design one in C# using this plugin: http://nppsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've done some looking and can't figure it out. Notepad++ already knows that **begin** and **end** go together (it will collapse a block based on them) when you choose the Verilog language. The bracket highlighting may be hard-coded and not configurable . . . but it seems like it should be configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've researched so far, there's no quick and easy way to do this unfortunately.

The only route I can see is to write a lexer in C# using [NppSharp](http://nppsharp.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite editor has fully customizable lexers (also for Verilog - verilog lexer isn't included by default, needs to be unpacked from MoreLexers.rar and be installed). SynWrite allows to hilite both begin / end words, when caret is over this begin-end block.
(This can be configured for a lexer).