# Has anyone developed a Notepad++ Lexer for "begin/end" block languages like Verilog and Pascal?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I found [this post from 8 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/626795/notepad-customised-syntax-highlighting). The conclusion was syntax highlighting of code blocks in languages using begin / end instead of braces would require writing a custom Lexer for NPP.

Here's an example with NPP 7.8.6 on Windows, showing the highlighting for Pascal:

[image]

The cursor is on `begin`, but there is no highlighting or other indication of the corresponding `end`.  As noted in the post referenced above, NPP already "knows" that begin and end go together (it will collapse a block based on them) as indicated by the red block structure lines with "-" controls.

In contrast, here is NPP displaying Perl:
[image]

The cursor is on the opening brace of the `foreach` loop, the corresponding closing brace is also highlighted.

In NPP Style Configurator, the brace highlighting is under "Global Styles"
[image]

There is no setting for "begin/end highlight style", and the code sample above shows that NPP does not treat begin/end pairs the same as braces for the purpose of highlighting.

[image]

Under the Pascal Language, `begin` and `end` are listed as one of the many "INSTRUCTION WORDS" and are colored accordingly. But there is nothing to indicate their role in code structure that I can find.

Has anyone ever written a custom lexer that can match begin/end pairs in that class of languages? Or is it already supported in the current version, but through a non-obvious feature ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Support for Pascal and Verilog

> The conclusion was syntax highlighting of code blocks in languages using begin / end instead of braces would require writing a custom Lexer

According to [Programming Languages | Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/programing-languages/) both Pascal and Verilog are already supported.

> Notepad++ supports for their syntax highlighting (customizable), syntax folding, auto-completion (customizable), function list (customizable via PCRE in xml file).
>
> If your beloved language is not in the list above, you can define it by your own easily, by using User Defined Languages System.

[image]

Comment: Please see edited question above for further clarification. The specific issue is about whether brace matching syntax highlighting can also apply to the begin/end code block in the languages that use that style.  I will investigate whether the User Defined Languages System can extend the syntax highlighting of existing languages.

Comment: After further consideration, I conclude the red block structure lines with `-` controls are 90% of what is needed. The current block has red lines, and others are brown, so it is possible to use the red lines to identify the current begin/end block. Not as obvious or consistent as the brace highlighting, but still quite usable.